# How to prevent UIButton "clipsToBounds" from clipping label?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

The following code:

```
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100,0,0,0)      
button.layer.cornerRadius   = 20
button.clipsToBounds = true
```

makes the button's label be cut off. Of course setting

```
clipsToBounds = false
```

Makes the round edges go away.
Anyway I can have both the label and the round edges?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `button.layer.maskToBounds = true;`

Comment: @CaptJak Sure seems to provide an answer to me. Could you explain how it doesn't?

Comment: @CaptJak Sure, it's not much of an answer, but it's still an answer. We shouldn't be deleting those from review, we should ask the user to provide more information, and downvote if necessary. Review isn't meant for that.

Comment: Please consider expanding on your answer to include why it works, and/or what the OP got wrong.